# Asterisk, why my isdn adapter TA can receive but not make calls?

Tags: asterisk

I have a b410p card ISDN BRI, configured with 4 NT ports.
On one NT port(2) I connect a ISDN phone(is working), on the other(4) I connect a TA(usb hamlet) connected to a VM with Windows 2000 running(is without networking, so is safe) running a soft-phone isdn called rvs-com.
On the isdn phone I can make calls and receive calls. The isdn TA can receive calls(but fail the answer), but when I make a call from the TA..the asterisk console is totally mute, I also set the debug intense with the command

```
pri set debug on span 4
```

When I make a call with the soft-phone, give error isdn 3302, but seems it don't connect to asterisk because as I said the console is mute.
What can be? I see the isdn ta put a international prefix before the call(+39), is this the problem? There is no way to remove this rule from Windows(as i know).
Those are my conf files

/etc/dahdi/system.conf

```
; Span 1: B4/0/1 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" AMI/CCS YELLOW 
group=0,11
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = bri_net_ptmp
channel => 1-2
context = default
group = 63

; Span 2: B4/0/2 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2" AMI/CCS YELLOW 
group=0,12
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = bri_net_ptmp
channel => 4-5
context = default
group = 63

; Span 3: B4/0/3 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 3" AMI/CCS YELLOW 
group=0,13
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = bri_net_ptmp
channel => 7-8
context = default
group = 63

; Span 4: B4/0/4 "B4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 4" (MASTER) AMI/CCS 
group=0,14
context=from-dahdi
switchtype = euroisdn
signalling = bri_net_ptmp
channel => 10-11
context = default
group = 63
```

/etc/asterisk/chan-dahdi.conf

```
[trunkgroups]
[channels]
language=it
context=local
switchtype=euroisdn
signalling=bri_net_ptmp
usecallerid=yes
callwaiting=yes
usecallingpres=yes
callwaitingcallerid=yes
threewaycalling=yes
transfer=yes
canpark=yes
cancallforward=yes
callreturn=yes
context=local
echocancel=yes
channel => 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11
echocancelwhenbridged=yes
group=1
callgroup=1
pickupgroup=1
overlapdial=yes
immediate=no
```

/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf

```
[from-dahdi]
include => local
exten => 1796522,1,Dial(DAHDI/g12/${EXTEN})
exten => 1796522,2,Hangup()

exten => 1796521,1,Dial(DAHDI/g14/${EXTEN})
exten => 1796521,2,Hangup()

exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,2,Dial(Local/${EXTEN},10,t,m)
exten => s,4,Hangup()

[local]
include => from-dahdi

exten => 1001,1,Dial(SIP/telefono1,20,Ttm)
same  => n,Hangup

exten => 7500,1,VoicemailMain(@mycontext)

exten => 600,1,Answer()
exten => 600,2,Playback(demo-echotest) ; Let them know what
exten => 600,3,Echo()                  ; Do the echo test
exten => 600,4,Playback(demo-echodone) ; Let them know it
exten => 600,5,Hangup()
```

Comment: Please stop spam. You have 3 the same questions with different headers in the last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, was only a problem of usb passtrough(I put a pci-e usb card, connect the usb-ta, pass to guest vm the entire pci-e usb card and not only one usb port as before ) and now works fine.